# Python: My program could print, but return None?

Tags: python, return

I have some problems when calling a function.

```
import random
board = []
solution=[]


def isConflict(x, y):

    for (i, j) in board:
        if x == i:
            return True
        if y == j:
            return True
        if abs(x - i) == abs(y - j):
            return True
    else:
        return False


def solve(x,y):
    for y in range(1, 9):
        if isConflict(x, y)==False:
            board.append((x, y))
            solve(x + 1,y)
            board.remove((x,y))
    if x > 8:
        solution.append(list(board))
        if len(solution)==92:
                return solution[random.randint(1,91)]

a=solve(1,1)
print(a)
```

This will give a None. However if I change the last part into:

```
    if x > 8:
        solution.append(list(board))
        if len(solution)==92:
                print(solution[random.randint(1,91)])

solve(1,1)
```

I could get the answer.
Therefore I couldn't do anything with the function because it always turns out to be a Nonetype and I want to use it in other functions. What shall I do? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed magical for a moment, but then I noticed that solve is recursive. The condition is true, but not in the topmost invocation.

You should do something with the value of solve instead of just calling it. I'd change it to this:

```
def solve(x,y):
    if x > 8:
        solution.append(list(board))
        if len(solution)==92:
            return solution[random.randint(1,91)]

    for y in range(1, 9):
        if isConflict(x, y)==False:
            board.append((x, y))
            s = solve(x + 1,y)
            board.remove((x,y))

            if s is not None:
                return s
```

Usually something is wrong if all paths of a function do not return a value.

Answer (score -1):

`solve` will only ever return anything if `x > 8`. In Python, if your function ends because it hits the end of its execution (rather than from a `return`), then it will return `None`.

If you want to return something when `x <= 8`, you should add an `else` and put your return there.

Comment: This is very unhelpful. See my answer.